Will the current vice president certify the election results also if running for and becoming elected president?
In the US, will the current vice president certify the election results also if running for and becoming elected president?

It is "inquiring."

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Inquiring minds want to know why you have not bothered with an actual question, and the body is a mere five irrelevant words of meta commentary.

I guess this is closely related https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60999/must-the-vice-president-preside-over-the-counting-of-the-electoral-college-votes?rq=1

Hasn't the same thing happened in the past?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Yes it has and if you also consider the current vice president certifying the results that keep them and the current president in office it increases the amount of times it has happened. And given that as of now only 46 different people have served as president even a small number makes up a decent size percentage wise.

@ohwilleke: https://www.alt-usage-english.org/excerpts/fxenquir.html

Is the question really "will they", or did you mean "should they" or "must they"? We can't predict the future. But regardless of wording, why wouldn't they certify the results if they won? A better question is whether they'll certify if they lose. Trump tried to get Pence to nullify the results when he lost, but the law has been changed to make it clear the VP has no such power.

@Barmar Given how congress has passed new law clarifying that the VP's role is purely ceremonial in leading the event I don't think that question can be raised again.  They also raised how many need to object to a states electoral votes before it goes to a full vote but that isn't really relevant here. https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/congress-approves-new-election-certification-rules-in-response-to-jan-6

There have been 4 VPs that ratified their own election as President.

John Adams       1796
Thomas Jefferson 1800
Martin Van Buren 1836
Bush Senior      1989

Its the basic constitutional practice the the President of the Senate confirms (or rather chairs the confirmation) the election results and that is simply the VP. No matter who won.

How many have ratified their opponents'election as president?  Why are the first three years divisible by four while Bush's is not?

@phoog Wll the question was specifically about certifing ones own election. As for why the others are divisable and Bush is not, I cant really tell you. Im not an american, somy knowledge on events that might have shiftet election or ratification dates is limited

The answer is yes regardless who wins, see Nixon 1960 precedent: he was VP then and also the Republican POTUS candidate in that election, but he lost to Kennedy, and conceded, as well as presided over the counting of the electoral votes in Congress.

For a more recent example of a VP cinfirming their election win: Bush Senior certified his election victory in 89

@SMSTJ: good point, you could even make that into an answer.

Al Gore in 2001 is a more recent example of a VP and presidential candidate who certified their opponent's win.

Nixon also had to deal with battling Electoral College results from Hawaii.
